# How to use last_insert_id() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My SQL statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (val1) VALUES('v1');      -- ID in first table
foo_id = SELECT last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO bar (val2) VALUES ('v2');     -- ID in second table
bar_id = SELECT last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO foobar (foo_id, bar_id, val3)
VALUES (foo_id, bar_id, 'text');          -- third table
```

The above is not working, it doesn't recognize the `foo_id = statement`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO foo (val1) VALUES ('v1');     -- ID in first table
SET @foo_id = last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO bar (val2) VALUES ('v2');     -- ID in second table
SET @bar_id = last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO foobar (foo_id, bar_id, val3)
VALUES (@foo_id, @bar_id, 'text');        -- third table
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I tried but getting this error: ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 2: Unknown system variable 'foo_id'

Comment: @diya you need to declare them first then, or use session variables (`@foo_id` etc). `declare foo_id INT;`

Comment: After declaration, i got the following - ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare foo_id INT' at line 1

Comment: i have declared foo_id as session variable like this: (set @foo_id := last_insert_id(); ) and finally it worked ! Thanks again !